# reading url parameter to a second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load contents from another page into a modal window by making an ajax call as follows.

```
$('body').on('click', '.append-report', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var bookingID = $(this).attr('bookingID');
  $.ajax({
     url: serverURL + "/inspection-report.html",
     type: "GET",
     data: {bookingID: bookingID },
     success: function(data){
        $('.modal-title').html('');
        $('.modal-body').html(data);
     }
   });});
```

I now want to read bookingID from inspection-report.html page, so that I can use it as follows:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
   name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
   var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
   results = regex.exec(location.search);
   return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
 }      
$(function(){
   var bookingID = getParameterByName("bookingID");         
});
```

My page does not read the value though. What could I be doing wrong? I'm I doing the right thing. Let me hear your insights. I can read parameters of the parent page's url. I need to read parameters to the 'child' page's url

Comment: If you're doing the right thing, it would work. You have the booking ID when making the ajax call, why not just pass it along instead of trying to parse it out of fetched markup?

Comment: That's a great idea @DanielB, it works. I was wondering why it would be difficult to retrieve GET parameters from the second page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an easier way to go about it. Just like @DanielB had suggested, I created a global variable accessible to both functions. This way, the child page will be able to read the value when the parent/the calling page writes it. On reading the url parameters, I'm still researching on that.